# Python XLRD no such file or directory

Tags: python, xlrd

I have a script working where I can open files if I pass the file name but now the number of files is increasing and it doesn't make sense to have to run the script on each file individually. So I decided to let python read al files in a directory.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Approved_LRPMP_Worksheets/"):
    for fyle in files:
        if fyle.endswith(".xlsx"):
            print fyle
            book = xlrd.open_workbook(fyle)
            print "book opened"
```

The output from this is:

```
I found a file: Agoura Hills LRPMP Review Sheet.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(fyle)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
  f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Agoura Hills LRPMP Review Sheet.xlsx'
```

The file is clearly being read, the name of the file is output in the command line just before I get the error. I feel like this is something simple that I should be catching but it has evaded me for the last 30 minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple fix, I was being stupid.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Approved_LRPMP_Worksheets/"):
    for fyle in files:
        if fyle.endswith(".xlsx"):
            print "I found a file: " + fyle
            fyleName = "Approved_LRPMP_Worksheets/"+fyle
            book = xlrd.open_workbook(fyleName)
```

And its done